# What is the keyboard shortcut for 'Commit' in the 'commit changes' dialogue in RubyMine (and PHPStorm, IntellijIDEA, PyCharm etc)?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, rubymine, pycharm

After choosing git --> commit changes, I have a dialogue as below with 'Commit' in the bottom right. It seems to have the 'i' underlined, however I can't work out what the shortcut for it is as none of the usual combinations e.g. Command-I, Command-Alt-I work. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Mnemonics usually work via the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, so it would be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Note that <kbd>Enter</kbd> confirms the dialog choice and if the focus is in the text area, it would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> mnemonic will also not work when you are entering the commit comment, so you should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl + Enter commits, but how can i chose commit and push. Also I get a dialog asking me to review or commit now and I cannot find out how to use my keyboard to say "ok" instead of "cancel", which is selected by default.

Answer (score -1):

click HELP and see the Keyboard shortcuts